# Is this a game theory problem or optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, game-theory

Consider a problem that looks for a $x$ that can make the following problem into some equilibrium state (similar to an equilibrium solution to a min-max problem in game theory)

$$ \max_x f(x)$$ $$ \min_x g(x)$$

subject to $$ f(x)  \geq a$$ $$
    g(x) \leq b $$

where $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions, and $x$ is from some
    set.

For example, as a customer, I am trying to choose a product of a given type to buy, but have to balance between product quality and price.  I will make the choice by making choices for the factors that the
    quality and/or price of the product depend on.

- $f$ represents the quality of a product,  and $a$ represents the lowest quality acceptable,
- $g$
  represents the price of the product,  and $b$ represents the available budget.
- $x$ is multi-dimensional and consists of factors that the
  quality and/or price of the product depend on, for example, the product model (thus manufacturer), seller (base price, purchase charge, shipping fee, tax, coupon, promo code, and any other discount), payment method (cashback credit cards, gift cards, and which card if i have multiple), and purchase timing.

The ideal solution is to find some $x$ so that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in equilibrium in some sense similar to the solution to a minmax problem in game theory, instead of maximizing $f$ and minimizing $g$ separately.

The constraints are not superficial. When there is an $x$ so that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in equilibrium, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ may not satisfy the constraints, and there should be a compromise in what we mean by "equilibrium" by constraints.
Note: If the constraints make the problem complicated, you may temporarily ignore them. I think we should start with a simpler problem, and understand them before considering a more complicated one.

My questions:

1. Is the  problem a game theory problem or optimization
   problem?

   Have there been well-defined/formulated problems similar to my problem?

   The problems I have heard in game theory is the min-max (or max-min)
   problem of the form $\min_x \max_y h(x,y)$, and the above problem
   doesn't seem to fall into the min-max problem form, because my problem has two objective functions (I am still in the process of understanding my problem and I am not sure if it has been well-formulated)

   In the optimization problems that I have heard, there is only one
   objective function which is either minimized or maximized over some
   independent variables.
2. What are some methods to solve such a problem in general?

Thanks.

Comment: The formula $\max\limits_xf(x)$ does not represent a problem, but a number (the maximum value attained by $x$). Therefore your opening sentence fails to say anything. If you mean toe say "maximise $f(x)$" you should do so, and not write a formula. But for maximising $f(x)$, the condition $f(x)\geq a$ is hardly a constraint (if it can be satisfied at all).

Comment: You haven't specified a mathematical problem. You have two objective functions, and the question is how to evaluate the trade-off between them. That can't be decided mathematically; it depends on the problem and what you're trying to achieve. You could subtract or divide the two functions, or any number of more complicated combinations. The similarity with minimax in game theory is merely superficial; the minimax problem does not ask for an "equilibrium in some sense"; it's a well-defined problem with a well-defined objective function for both players, who pursue their goals independently.

Comment: @Marc: (1) about using $\max$ and $\min$ to formulate an optimization problem, what you said makes sense to me. Do you have some references that mention that? (2) I am not just maximizing $f(x)$, but try to find some $x$ so that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in equilibrium similar to the solution to a minmax problem in game theory, yet subject to the two constraints. So the two constraints are not superficial. If the constraints make the problem too complicated, we can start with simplifying the problem by ignoring the constraints. (see my update)

Comment: @joriki: I am still in the process of understanding and formulating the problem, so I am not sure if my problem is well defined. My post is  asking whether there have been well-defined/formulated problems similar to mine. In my question, a solution is one $x$ that makes the $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ fall in equilibirum in some sense similar to the equilibrium solution to a minmax problem in game theory. I don't know if there have been different possibilities to characterize  "sense" already. I also like to know if there have been problems in game theory which are close to my problem.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on your motivation for this problem so that we could suggest ways to make it well-defined? For instance, are you perhaps trying to model firm reputation? Or are you just trying to model a relationship between the firm and a particular client? Who are the players? What is the conflict (or point of cooperation)? Give us a story and maybe we can suggest the optimization problem or equilibrium concept that fits it.

Comment: @Shane: As a customer, I am trying to choose a product of a given type to buy, but have to balance between product quality and price.  I will make the choice by choosing the product model (thus manufacturer), seller, payment method (cashback credit cards, gift cards, and which card if i have multiple), timing, and any other factors that can affect the product price and quality.

Comment: @Tim. OK -- then it seems your customer needs a utility function that's decreasing in price and increasing in quality. Then, if this utility function is known to the firm, and the firm knows the utility you get from your best alternative, it could try to maximize its profits from selling to you, conditional on the constraint that you prefer their option to your best alternative. That's a sequential game and you're using backwards induction to find the (subgame perfect) Nash equilibrium...

Comment: And it's also an  optimization problem for the firm. Basically, it's minimizing costs, subject to the constraint that the product has to be better than or equal to your best alternative.

Comment: @shane: (1) What are some ways to create such a utility function out of $f$ and $g$? (2) The utility function is not supposed to let the seller or manufacture know, but only to the customer, me, for buying a product of a given type. Is my problem an optimization problem rather than a game theory one?

Comment: I mean, you could just use $u(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ or something. The choice is really up to you. If the manufacturer does not observe $u$, then it's a game of incomplete information. I still don't think your problem is sufficiently defined to answer the latter question. But I will say that (non-cooperative) game theory is based on strategic consequences where agents are individually optimizing, so it sounds to me like you're trying to describe a game, but that obviously will have some optimization cooked in.

Answer (score 1):

From what you say it sounds like it should be a problem of constrained optimization.  as Shane has said, you need to take a stand on the utility function, how the consumer balances benefits and costs.  The standard way in economics is to assume there is a price (usually linear, but it doesn't have to be) http://www.unc.edu/~normanp/unc410week3.pdf  Then your constraint set is your income, and you maximize your utility (like your f function) subject to the prices of the goods and your budget set (the set x belongs to). Remember that the minimax result of game theory is for zero-sum games, that is, what ever you win I lose, so implies that your f and g functions are identical, so even if there is a game-theoretic interpretation, it's not clear to me that minimax would be the correct solution anyway. Way more details in David Krep's book A Course in Microecnomic Theory.